# javascript validation of textbox in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have one text box and button in asp.net like

```
<tr>
<td style="width: 100px">
 <asp:Label ID="lbltime" runat="server" Text="Enter Time"></asp:Label>
</td>
  <td style="width: 100px">
  <asp:TextBox ID="Txttime" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>         
 </tr>
<tr>
  <td style="width: 100px" align="center">
  <asp:Button ID="Btntime" runat="server" Text="Button" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Now I want to write JavaScript code  to validate on my textbox which work when I click on button.
Now I want to know how to call function of JavaScript in button and 
the function should do work like is 
button should send the text box value to the function and function should check the value to integer number only. And if not found should give the error message in the dialog box that "please enter value in integer only".

I'm trying the JavaScript like this:

```
function isNumberKey(textboxvalue)
      {
          evt=textboxvalue.text;
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            textboxvalue.text="Enter in Integer Only";
            return false;

         return true;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an <asp:[CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) /> for this.

```
<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1"
       ControlToValidate="myTextbox"
       ErrorMessage="Enter Integer only!"
       OnServerValidate="ServerValidation"
       OnClientValidate="isNumberKey"
       runat="server"/>
```

Your validation function looks like this:

```
function isNumberKey(oSrc, args) {
{
     evt=textboxvalue.text; 
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode 
     if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) 
        args.isValid = false; 

     args.IsValid = true; 
}
```

If you just want to check the data type, you can use a CompareValidator:

```
<asp:CompareValidator id="CompareValidator1" 
         runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter Integer only!" Operator="DataTypeCheck"
         ControlToValidate="Txttime" Type="Integer" />
```

The validators check on the client side if JavaScript is available AND on server side. All JavaScript will be generated for you.
On the server, you always have to check, whether your page is valid or not:

```
protected void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Page.IsValid)
  {
     ... // do your work on the server
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont want to use server side validation thats why i am using javascript.Please help me to correct my code.

Comment: You should always check on the server as well!! To test wheter your input is an integer, you can use the CompareValidator (I'll add a sample). The Validator controls check on the client AND on the server.

Comment: Thanks i want to pass text value as argument   <asp:Button ID="Btntime" onclick:"myfuntion()" runat="server" Text="Button" /> how to pass my text value into the argument.

Comment: you would have to use the client id of the textbox to access the value. Depending on your context it could be Txttime.value

Comment: it Not Working. And we cant Check it also because javascript doesnot allow to debug the code.then how to corret it

Comment: i m trying like this   <input type="button" title="hello" id="Button2" runat="server" onclick="isNumberKey();" onserverclick="Button2_ServerClick" /> now i need to pass argument in onclick property. how it should be done.

Comment: is there any reason why you not want to use the built-in controls like jayp and I suggest? It makes live so much easier and you don't have to think about how to pass control id's. You don't have to think about JavaScript at all, it just works. Just use the CompareValidator from my sample code. What is the goal of your validator?

Comment: you could add this attribute to your textbox: onchange="isNumberKey(TxtTime.value)". It will be called as soon as the textbox looses focus

Comment: since i am working on government project. we cant make much more load on serverside to check for validation.so to reduce the load we are trying to validation with javascripting. so i hav tried my javascript function but it doesnt working.it is checking only 1 char not entire string.it should do like this.the function should hav argument as textbox value and it accept when it is integer otherwise should display error messege(please enter Integer only).

Comment: can u tell is there any IDE to debug the javascript? if yes please give the link

Comment: i have got the answer. function IsNumeric(TextBox1)
{
 var m = document.getElementById( 'TextBox1').value;
    alert(m);
var anum=/(^\d+$)/;

if (!anum.test(document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").value))
{
    alert("Order Value must be a valid integer");
    document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").focus();
    return false;
}
}

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET has built-in validation controls that are able to cope with things like this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx

In addition, make sure you don't rely on client-side validation only - check for an integer on the server-side, and reject the input if it isn't an integer.

Comment: Yes. I want Client Side validation Only thats why i am using javascript.Please help me to correct my code.

Comment: The built-in controls validate on the client-side.

Comment: which inbuilt function you talking about.please give example

Comment: There are lots of examples on the page I linked to in my answer.

Comment: can u tell is there any IDE to debug the javascript? if yes please give the link

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use like  `var control = $("#<%= txtMyControl.ClientID %>"); return control;`
?? then do standard validation ??